# jQuery $.post works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a problem with jQuery $.post. It works only once. Here is the code:

```
$(document).on('change','#hour', function(){
    $('#date').text(output + " " + $('#hour').val() + ":" + $('#minute').val());
    $.post("functions/zmiana.php", 
    {
        godz: $('#hour').val() + ":" + $('#minute').val(),
    },
    function(data, status){
        var tekst = $('#team').text();
        var dl = tekst.length;
        var por = tekst.substring(dl-7, dl-3);
        if (por == "TEAM"){
            $('#team').text(tekst.substring(0,dl-7) + 'TEAM ' + data);          
       }
    });
});
```

When I change value of #hour select field for the first time. All works fine.
But when i try do do this second time, Only The value of #date field is changed but $.post don`t work. It seems that 'change' event works fine because it changes the date in #date field.

I was trying few solutions from THIS site, but nothing worked for me.
Thank You in advance.

Lukas

Comment: anything in the console?

Comment: Show your html markup please.

Comment: First, tidy up your code; second, provide HTML code.

Comment: Perhaps because you are doing the event on the document

Comment: $.post in your code works fine in provided code senond, third, ... times. I checked it here http://codepen.io/kvic2/pen/EVxoYP    But you use "output" variable that is not defined here, I removed it when I checked the code.

Comment: @zlen it is not done on the document. It is done on `#hour`. It's delegated from `document`.

Comment: @Lukasz : From where comes the `output` variable ??? Please make a jsfiddle to understand your problem (https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Ok, i solved the issue. $.post was working normally, but was retutning empty value.

Comment: @Lukasz : Ok, cool :). But, if you don't put the entire problem and code, we can't solve it ! Remember to this